# Origen y significado de "la calavera no chilla"

Tags: modismos, letras-de-canciones

Viendo varios videos de Les Luthiers, he notado que la frase "la calavera no chilla" aparece varias veces en sus bromas.

¿Puede que sea una expresión argentina? ¿Qué significa y cuál es el origen de la frase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Proverbios argentinos: Wikiquote](http://es.wikiquote.org/wiki/Proverbios_argentinos):

> "Calavera no chilla" (la frase completa es "Calavera no chilla y el piola [experimentado] se las banca [soporta]", en lunfardo "calavera" es el sujeto que practica juergas nocturnas y por esto en ocasiones hace peligrar su salud)

Significaría: *Si ayer trasnochaste, no te quejes.*

*Lunfardo* según la RAE:

> Habla que originariamente empleaba, en la ciudad de Buenos Aires y sus alrededores, la gente de clase baja. Parte de sus vocablos y locuciones se introdujeron posteriormente en la lengua popular y se difundieron en el español de la Argentina y el Uruguay.

Comment: Quité tu enlace a la definición en inglés porque iba directamente a un anuncio de una escuela.  Eso no está permitido en Stackexchange.  (The link to the definition was resolving to the home page.)

Answer (score 0):

Mi padre decía eso cuando salimos y regresábamos a la madrugada nos levantábamos para ir a trabajar y si decíamos *que sueño tengo* o nos quejábamos de la hora, el nos decia, *vamos, vamos el calavera no chilla*.

El calavera es un fiestero, pero no se porque no chilla. Supongo porque el muerto no puede hablar y no se queja.